# laravel - Get parent category tile using custom model function

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined parent relation within category class using 'parent_id' as mentioned below, I want to print category title with parent title like `mens > show`. but it throws

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$title

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'categories';


    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }   

    public function withParentTitle(): string
    {               
        if($this->parent()){            
            return $this->parent()->title.' > '. $this->title;
        }
        return $this->title;
    }   


}
```

---

CategoryController

................

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){        
        $categories = Category::get();
        foreach($categories as $category){
            echo $category->withParentTitle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

according to laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

you can use `accessors` by this way

```
public function getParentTitleAttribute(){
  return $this->parent ? $this->parent->title . '>' . $this->title : $this->title;
}
```

then call `$category->parent_title;`

Comment: You are using `accessor`, not `mutator`. Anyway, this suggestion is not directly related to the problem itself.

Comment: thanks for your note , edited , but why my code not related to problem ?

Comment: Your solution didn't mention any bit to the problem `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$title`, though he can still use it by copy & pasting your code :)

Comment: could you seen last edit if it matched the problem or not ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the call without `()` like this :

```
public function withParentTitle(): string
{               
    if($this->parent()){            
        return $this->parent->title.' > '. $this->title;
    }
    return $this->title;
}
```

Because if you use the `()` you are callin the relation as query builder and you can use other closures :

```
$this->parent()->where('title', 'foo')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function withParentTitle(): string
    {               
        // Your $this->parent() would always be true, 
        // use $this->parent()->exists() instead
        if($this->parent()->exists()){            
            // $this->parent() refers to the relationship, 
            // you can't get title out of the relationship object, 
            // unless you retrieve it using $this->parent
            return $this->parent->title.' > '. $this->title;
        }
        return $this->title;
    }
```